# Connecting to a local .sql database with VS Code

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-code

I need to understand how to connect to a sample .sql database in VS Code that's stored on my hard drive. I'm studying for MCSE 70-461 on SQL queries. I decided to use the mssql extension in VS Code. The mssql shows up as just SQL in the bottom of VS Code.

But, I can't figure out how to connect to the sample database provided with the course. I tried to set up a connection using the prompts on MS SQL: Connect but got an error saying

"unable to connect using the information provided"

I'm pretty sure everything's set up correctly because it said the sql install was successful, I can see the database in my folder tagged w/ a vscode ribbon, and I can open the database in VS Code by double-clicking on it in the folder.

Please see the attached screenshots and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Here are links to my screen shots.

This one shows what I believe to be a successful installation of mssql

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBzBz.jpg

This one shows VS Code is able to recognize and open the database

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyxF8.jpg

Answer (score 0):

MS-SQL database has an .mdf extension, try installing the free edition, create a database then execute your .sql file.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: 1. download and install express edition: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads -- quite a long way but try researching in google on how to install ms-sql server, once you're done with it, research again on how to create a database, after that, your TSQL2012.sql file contains create table etc, just paste it in a new query under the database you created. You should be able to connect in your VS if you successfully installed and created the sql server.